# Set string value with formatting symbols in js/jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have on jsp page:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var test = {};
    test.id = ${docId};
    test.message = ${message};
</script>
```

If message equal:

```
'hello world'
```

I'll get error in page: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"`

How set string value in js? if value have `\n`, `\'` or other formatting symbols

Comment: `test.id = '${docId}';` (Assuming the `${}` syntax is how your interping server-side variables)

Comment: Is that the JSP Expression Language you are using there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Example on Glassfish4 server.

The following JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>initJsObject</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- prepare attributes, just for testing -->
<c:set var="docId" value="123"></c:set>
<c:set var="message" value="'hello world'"></c:set>
<c:set var="lines" value="'line1\nline2'"></c:set>
<c:set var="backslashN" value="'\\\\\n'"></c:set>

<textarea id="txt" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = {};
    test.id = ${docId};
    test.message = ${message};
    test.lines = ${lines};
    test.backslashN = ${backslashN};
    console.log(test);

    document.getElementById("txt").value += "id: " + test.id + "\n";
    document.getElementById("txt").value += "message:" +  test.message + "\n\n";
    document.getElementById("txt").value += "lines:\n"+ test.lines + "\n\n";
    document.getElementById("txt").value += "backslashN: ("+ test.backslashN + ")\n\n";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

generates the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>initJsObject</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- prepare attributes fot testing -->
<textarea id="txt" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = {};
    test.id = 123;
    test.message = 'hello world';
    test.lines = 'line1\nline2';
    test.backslashN = '\\n';
    console.log(test);

    document.getElementById("txt").value += "id: " + test.id + "\n";
    document.getElementById("txt").value += "message:" +  test.message + "\n\n";
    document.getElementById("txt").value += "lines:\n"+ test.lines + "\n\n";
    document.getElementById("txt").value += "backslashN: ("+ test.backslashN + ")\n\n";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And outputs in browser:

> id: 123
>   message:hello world
>
> lines:
>   line1
>   line2
>
> backslashN: (\n)

As you see the `\n` in the attribute string `'line1\nline2'` will be evaluated as new line.
On the other side, if you need the sting `\n` to be presented as text, you need to escape `'\\\\\n'`